# Loading an Image into StandardListItem inside ListView BB10

Tags: qml, cascade, blackberry-10

I want to display a list of contacts inside a StandardListItem. The data is retrieved from sql with QArrayBytes representing the Image.

The StandardListItem accepts a title, status, description and an image. But setting the image is not working.

How to set the image bytes in QML inside the StandardListItem.

PS: I don't want to make a custom list item component

Thanks you,

Answer (score 2):

You actually need to use "imageSource" not "image".  You can see a working example here: https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/device_platform/data_access/using_data_source.html

Answer (score 0):

Been fighting that myself, take a look at [this sample](http://blackberry.github.io/Cascades-Samples/imageloader.html) it uses the QlistDataModel I've been trying to modify it without much success... [The documentation](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__qlistdatamodel.html) is pretty sucky they don't tell you much in there

Comment: Try to create a custom standardListItem ... it worked for me. Use then inside the cpp class the setImage function